# How to change a string into a number from a form? (Keeps turning it into string)

Tags: javascript

I am kind of confused on why my javascript is not turning my strings into numbers.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Question #1</h3>
                <label for="exampleSelect1">Question?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="q1">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#submitBtn").on("click", function(){
  event.preventDefault();
    var q1 = $("#q1").val().trim();
    var q2 = $("#q2").val().trim();
    var q3 = $("#q3").val().trim();
    var q4 = $("#q4").val().trim();
    var q5 = $("#q5").val().trim();
    var q6 = $("#q6").val().trim();
    var q7 = $("#q7").val().trim();
    var q8 = $("#q8").val().trim();
    var q9 = $("#q9").val().trim();
    var q10 = $("#q10").val().trim();

  var newFriend = {
    name: $("#inputName").val().trim(),
    photo: $("#inputPic").val().trim(),
    scores: [
    parseFloat(q1),
    parseFloat(q2),
    parseFloat(q3),
    parseFloat(q4),
    parseFloat(q5),
    parseFloat(q6),
    parseFloat(q7),
    parseFloat(q8),
    parseFloat(q9),
    parseFloat(q10),

    ]
  };
```

When I console.log(newFriend) it keeps turning the scores into strings. I have tried Number(), parseInt() and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It might be just the way that console.log outputs the data. When storing this data in your database (I presume) is it correct?

Comment: Yeah I am getting the data from my api

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         console.log(data[i]);
         
} @jeff

Comment: just multiply it with 1 . suppose number is 200 . multiply it with 1 as 1*200

Comment: I think it has something to do with my server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as it should the way it is.

But, based on some of the comments you've made, it appears that this code is running on a server and not in the client and therefore is being sent over HTTP, where everything is a string. You really should edit your question to fully explain the environment that the code is running in.

You can see a slimmed down version of your code working below and you'll see that the data is numeric in the array. I have just changed the event that triggers the code to the `change` event of the `select`.

Lastly, there is no need to call `.trim()` on your `select` values because you aren't including any spaces in the `option` elements to begin with. `trim()` should be used whenever there is user input.

```js
$("#q1").on("change", function(){
    var q1 = $("#q1").val().trim();


  var newFriend = {
    scores: [
      parseFloat(q1),

    ]
  };
  
  console.log(newFriend.scores[0], typeof newFriend.scores[0]);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <h3>Question #1</h3>
  <label for="exampleSelect1">Question?</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="q1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseInt and pass the radix too. Else unary operator can also be used to convert string to number.

Note there was no value attribute in option.

```js
$("#submitBtn").on("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var q1 = parseInt($("#q1").val().trim(), 10)
  console.log(typeof q1)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <h3>Question #1</h3>
  <label for="exampleSelect1">Question?</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="q1">
                    <option value = "1" >1</option>
                    <option value = "2">2</option>
                    <option value = "3">3</option>
                    <option value = "4">4</option>
                    <option value = "4">5</option>
                </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This looks like it would work but my server is still sending back a string. Is it because I am pushing it as a req.body using body-parser?

Comment: When no ‘value’ attribute is specified for an ‘option’ the element’s text content becomes its value. The attribute is only needed when you want the value to be something different.